# My Documents Redirect, Server no longer available, recover from local cache?

Tags: windows-7, roaming-profile, folder-redirection

We had a major reshuffle in our company. Servers got 'removed' and domains disconnected. It's a whole mess I'm untangling.

One users laptop recently crashed. I can't get it to boot into Windows despite trying all day yesterday with various recovery options. There are some very important documents on the disk I need to recover. They're all located in My Documents. I've now stuck the disk in a caddy and I can browse the disk.

I've just discovered that his my documents is in fact a redirect to a server which no longer exists. It hasn't existed for quite some time but he's been able to store documents in My Documents despite the server share it's directed too not existing.

Confirmed this by navigating to : x:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent\

Here, recent documents reference a share which has not existing for quite some time. The documents post date this servers removal.

So, there must be a local cache where these documents are stored offline until in theory they could be uploaded to the server. Where is this cache? how can I access / discover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into [systemdrive]:\windows\csc. This is the default location for Offline Files